# use a relative path in requirements.txt to install a tar.gz file with pip

Tags: python, pip

We're using a requirements.txt file to store all the external modules needed. Every module but one is gathered from internet. The other one is stored on a folder under the one holding the requirements.txt file.

BTW, this module can be easily installed with pip install

I've tried using this:

```
file:folder/module
```

or this:

```
file:./folder/module
```

or even this:

```
folder/module
```

but always throws me an error.
Does anyone know which is the right way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In the current version of pip (1.2.1) the way relative paths in a requirements file are interpreted is ambiguous and semi-broken. There is an open issue on the pip repository which explains the various problems and ambiguities in greater detail:

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/328

Long story short the current implementation does not match the description in the pip documentation, so as of this writing there is no consistent and reliable way to use relative paths in `requirements.txt`.

THAT SAID, placing the following in my `requirements.txt`:

```
./foo/bar/mymodule
```

works when there is a `setup.py` at the top level of the `mymodule` directory. Note the lack of the `file::` protocol designation and the inclusion of the leading `./`. This path is not relative to the `requirements.txt` file, but rather to the current working directory. Therefore it is necessary to navigate into the same directory as the `requirements.txt` and then run the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I don't know what the deal is, but on Windows, only `-e ./foo/bar/mymodule` worked, instead of `.\foo\bar\mymodule`

Comment: This answer from 2012y, is requirements.txt still not support relative path?

Comment: Year 2021, `../foo` in requirements.txt works with pip 18.1

Answer (score 21):

Its based off the current working directory (find with os.getcwd() if needed) and the relative path you provide in the requirements file.

Your requirements file should look like this:

```
fabric==1.13.1
./some_fir/some_package.whl
packaging==16.8
```

Note this will only work for .whl files not .exe

Remember to keep an eye on the pip install output for errors.

Answer (score 6):

For me only the `file:` directive worked. This even works with AWS SAM, i.e. `sam build`. Here is my `requirements.txt` and the englishapps is my own custom Python package that I need in AWS Lambda

```
requests
file:englishapps-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: This worked also with micropip.

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned before, the files are relative to the current working directory, not the `requirement.txt`.

Since v10.0 [requirements files support environment variables](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#using-environment-variables) in the format: `${VAR_NAME}`.  This could be used as a mechanism to specify a file location relative to the `requirements.txt`.  For example:

```
# Set REQUIREMENTS_DIRECTORY outside of pip
${REQUIREMENTS_DIRECTORY}/folder/module
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the environment manager called Pipenv to manage this use case.
The steps after you do the `pipenv install` for a new project:

`pipenv install -e app/deps/fastai` (`-e` is editable, and is optional)

then you will see the following line in your Pipfile:
`fastai = {editable = true,path = "./app/deps/fastai"}`

here's similar issues:

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/209#issuecomment-337409290
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53507226/7032846

Answer (score -1):

A solution that worked for me both for local and remote files (via Windows share). Here an example of `requirements.txt`

```
file:////REMOTE_SERVER/FOLDER/myfile.whl
```