# Installing dependencies of a local dependency with pipenv

Tags: python, dependency-management, setup.py, pipenv, pipfile

#### Background

We have project with the following high-level directory structure*

```
./datascience/
├── core
│   └── setup.py
├── notebooks
│   └── Pipfile
└── web
    └── Pipfile
```

<sup>*Excluded all the irrelevant files and directories for brevity.</sup>

The `core` package is a library. It's a dependency of both the `notebooks` and `web` applications.

The `core` package, [being a library](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipfile-vs-setup-py), has its dependencies specified in `setup.py`

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    install_requires=[
        'some-dependency',
        'another-dependency'
    ]
)
```

The `web` and `notebooks` applications are using [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io) for dependency management. Their dependencies are specified in a `Pipfile`.

For example, here's how the `web` dependencies are specified in `web/Pipfile`:

```
[packages]
datascience-core = {path = "./../core"}
flask = "~= 1.0"
```

Notice how the `core` dependency is a local dependency, hence the relative path.

#### Problem

Doing a `pipenv install` from inside the the `web` or `notebooks` directory, does not install the dependencies of the `core` library as I expected!

I also tried using a `Pipfile` for `core`, hoping that pipenv would pick it up in its graph and download all the nested dependencies. But it doesn't.

How can dependencies of the `core` app be installed automatically when pipenv is installing dependencies for the `web` or `notebooks` app?

Answer (score 40):

Found a solution thanks to this comment in a pipenv issue thread: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/209#issuecomment-337409290

I've continued listing the `core`'s dependencies in `setup.py`.

I've changed the `web` and `notebook` apps to use an *editable* installation of the `core` package.
This was done by running the following in both the `web` and `notebooks` directory:

```
pipenv install --editable ../core
```

It produced this diff

```
[packages]
- datascience-core = {path = "./../core"}
+ datascience-core = {editable = true,path = "./../core"}
```

Now running `pipenv install` from the `web` and `notebooks` directory results in the installation of the `core` package and its dependencies!

It also solved another very annoying problem, which was having to `pipenv install` every time there was a change in `core`. Now it picks up development changes without having to re-install the local package!

Comment: is there a way to use pipenv's Pipfile for core? Is there a reason to use setup.py?

Comment: @KevenWang can have a `Pipfile` in core alongside the `setup.py` file. It can be used to aid development for example. The `[packages]` section would have an entry for `datascience-core = {editable = true, path = "."}` and you could have a `[dev-packages]` section with dev tools.

But it's not a replacement for the `setup.py` file. Because the core package is a library, and not an application, we have to specify its dependencies
in the `setup.py` file instead of the `Pipfile`. This ensures that Python will install the core's dependencies when an application is installing the core package.