# Troubleshooting MoviePy Deployment Issues in Python

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, imagemagick, moviepy

My code is currently working on my local machine with **moviepy** in flask, and I want to deploy it as a web application. I was able to successfully deploy it on Heroku using this buildpack: https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick. However, it's consuming too much RAM, and I can't afford the $500 package for 4GB of RAM. I'm now trying to deploy it on the Google App Engine standard environment, but I'm getting this error: `This error may be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer.` Can you please suggest the best solution for deploying it?

I was able to successfully deploy it on Heroku using this buildpack: https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. GAE Standard installs the contents of your `requirements.txt` file using pip ([see documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#dependencies)). `pip` is used to download and install packages directly from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) (Python Package Index)
2. The buildpack you referenced downloads and installs `imagemagick`. If you look at the buildpack, you'll notice that `imagemagick` is being downloaded from a **custom url**. This means it isn't on PyPI and so can't be installed by just calling `pip install <package>`
3. If you must use GAE Standard, then there might be 2 options you can try

   i) Download/install `imagemagick` to your Application folder and deploy it together with your App (you'll have to make sure all relative urls for accessing it works)

   ii) Download the tar file of `imagemagick` to the root of your Application folder and add it to your requirements.txt file using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12921216/15211203) and then see if GAE standard installs it during deployment

Alternatively, you can switch to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) which allows you to do essentially the same thing as the build pack you mentioned i.e. you create a docker file, issue commands to download/install what you want from whatever url, then issue commands to install the contents of your `requirements.txt` file

Comment: Thank you very much sir. i deployed on cloud run and it's working very fast